# FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "fe80::1%lo0"

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, ssl

Can someone help me why this is happening when I'm trying to connect to database or `rails s`?

In my pg_hba.conf file I have this:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     Andrew                                trust
#host    replication     Andrew        127.0.0.1/32            trust
#host    replication     Andrew        ::1/128                 trust

local all all md5
```

Maybe I'm doing it wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What does your connection string look like?  Why aren't you just connecting to `::1` ?  Unrelated, but your `local all all md5` can't work as it is preempted by your `local all all trust`

Comment: @jjanes I'm not exactly sure where `“fe80::1%lo0”` came from? And how do I get back to `::1`?

Comment: Operating system? Are you on Mac OS X ? Something else? What OS/version, PostgreSQL version? Any recent changes to the OS?

Comment: @CraigRinger Thanks for helping! I'm using Mac OS X, version 10.9.2. And I'm using the PostgreSQL standalone software that I downloaded, version 9.3.2.0.

Comment: OK, and any recent changes to the OS/config? What's your connection string / parameters (since it's rails, the contents of your `database.yml`) ?  If you connect with `psql -h localhost` does that produce the same error?

Comment: @CraigRinger yes it does throw the same error with `psql -h localhost`

Comment: but what about `-h 127.0.0.1`? Your DNS resolver certainly seems to be doing something crazy, returning the link-local address like that.

Comment: fe80::1%lo0 is an IPv6 link-local address assigned to the loopback 0 interface and is a valid localhost. It shouldn't be removed from /etc/hosts. The correct solution is to allow the ip address in pg_hba.conf as @Daniel suggested.

Answer (score 22):

I had the same problem.  somehow, this line was added to my /etc/hosts file:

```
fe80::1%lo0    localhost
```

commenting out or removing that line from /etc/hosts should fix it

```
sudo vi /etc/hosts
#fe80::1%lo0    localhost
```

Comment: I have the exact same thing in mine. Yosemite. very odd. it seems to be a Yosemite bug or maybe a bandaid they left in. see http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/74167/postgresql-tries-to-connect-to-fe801-permission-denied my connection problems were oddly intermittent.

Comment: You and me both @felix! Strange thing is; I've had Yosemite 10.10.1 for several days before this started happening.

Comment: Same thing happened to me several times after software updates. OS X 10.9.5

Comment: Wonderful! Helped me with that one.

Answer (score 16):

I'm on OSX 10.9.3 and Postgres 9.3.4.

I've managed to resolve this problem in the following way:

First find your `pg_hba.conf` file by starting up psql with `psql -h 127.0.0.1` and executing [`SHOW hba_file;`](https://askubuntu.com/a/256711):

```
              hba_file
-------------------------------------
 /usr/local/var/postgres/pg_hba.conf
(1 row)
```

Now add the following line to `pg_hba.conf`:

```
host    all             all             fe80::1%lo0/128         trust
```

and reload the configuration via [`select pg_reload_conf();`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17473267/587320) within `psql`.

Now you should be able to connect via `psql -h fe80::1%lo0`.

Comment: That's useful to work around it, but the OS is _so_ broken if it's doing that. Something's badly busted. Personally, if I couldn't track it down I'd be reinstalling.

Comment: thanks, this worked for me!  on PostgreSQL 9.4.0 on x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0

Answer (score 3):

Oo, that's an interesting one.

Assuming you're connecting to `localhost` (you didn't say and didn't show your `database.yml`), it appears that `localhost` is resolving to [an IPv6 link-local address with zone index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Link-local_addresses_and_zone_indices).

If you use `::1` or `127.0.0.1` it should work.

This is very likely an operating system misconfiguration or bug, so lots more detail (see comment above) should be added to the question if you want any concrete advice on that.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the cause was calling `sudo rails server -p 80`.

I bound the rails server to port 80 so that I wouldn't have to specify a port in the url `localhost:3000` during development.  This appears to write `fe80::1%lo0»localhost` to my `/etc/hosts` file.

Try commenting out the line in your hosts file, then running `rails s -p 3000`

Answer (score 0):

Actually,

The same error occurs for me when I execute `pg_dump` command to take backup of my server database (external) like below

```
'/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin'/pg_dump -d "<database_name>" -h <server_name> -U <db_user_name> -f <destination_path>
```

I solved it (work around) by replacing my `<server_name>` to my actual server IP (`10.1.0.18`).

So the issue here is my system didn't understand the `<server_name>` host.

It might solve permanently when you add `<server_name>` host in /private/etc/hosts file.

Answer (score -1):

Another variant: if IPv6 is not used in the network, you can just disable it. On Windows IPv6 service also can be disabled.

Comment: Google translated: "Still as an option: if the network does not use ipv6, then simply turn it off, also if the Windows operating system turns off the support service ipv6"